# What can be causing the huge latency for Classic ASP pages

Tags: performance, iis, asp-classic

The entire code that is placed inside the page is:

```vb
Response.Write ("This is a very simple page created with ASP.")
```

Yet this page will produce the following potential errors:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

or

> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

or a simple

> timeout error

The CPU seems to be running at 70+% capacity and memory at 50% according to our hosts CP. We try a recycle of the application pool and stopping and re-starting the site but both of which makes no difference to the CPU or memory. Without any changes to any of the code on the site, after a period of time the site and page will return back to normal and the page with the code above will load in under a second.

Possibly associated with this is that the entire application can work fine for months but then experience a period of very long latency (> 30secs, 1 minute and sometimes 2 minutes). This problem can then come and go. It may be around for anywhere between a few hours to a few days and then disappear.

Our host says that it is a problem with our application. I put the page with the code above and we still get the error or the latency and therefore it must be something to do with what happens before a Classic ASP page is loaded.

What part of the classic ASP platform could be causing this. Any suggestions as to what we can do to isolate the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that all of the DLLs assosciated with classic-asp are registered properly and are they installed in SysWOW64 if you are on a 64 bit system?